# SQL Server : FOR XML PATH: the identifier that starts with ... is too long. maximum length is 128

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

While trying to create an XML result using `FOR XML PATH` in T-SQL (SQL Server 2008) I stumbled across this error:

> The identifier that starts with ... is too long. maximum length is 128

The line it errors on is pretty deep and more than 128 characters long:

```
GlobalTradeItemInformation/tradingPartnerNeutralTradeItemInformation/cataloguePrice/tradeItemPrice/priceBracket/@rangeUnitOfMeasure'
```

Besides using a subselect with another `FOR XML` statement in it, what are the options to resolve this? For example, is this a setting in SQL Server which can be changed? Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting that you can change for this. The issue that you're running into is detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx). Search that page for "identifier" and you'll see that the 128 length is hard-coded.

Comment: Thanks, then there is no other way then to use subselects more often.